# FoxPro 6.0 - adding rows in a Select query

Tags: sql, visual-foxpro, foxpro

I have rows in a dbf file that represent one per month, where months go from -250 to +600. There is a variable in each row called t_from that represents the month. I want to add the rows for months -150 to 0. How do I do this? Is it possible to do it within a Select statement, or do I need something more? I am already grouping by a number of variables in the 'group by' statement.

Sample data, simplified to show only one grouping variable:

```
Bus_LINE    t_from
--------    -------
ABC         -250
ABC         -249
ABC         ...
ABC         +599
ABC         +600
ZXC         -250
ZXC         -249
ZXC         ...
ZXC         +599
ZXC         +600
...
etc
```

Comment: Range -250 to +600 includes range -150 to 0 already. What are you asking really? You are saying that you are grouping by in 'group by' statement but we don't see any code. Please explain your problem clearly. There is "insert into ... select ..." but your question is not understandable.

Comment: I'm not really following a question, but it seems like a for loop with an insert or append would work.

Comment: Apologies, not being clear. I actually solved it myself afterwards. I'll post the solution below (perhaps then the question will become clear!) Many thanks, Joe.

Answer (score 0):

```
    **** Assign variables to the input files ****
moses_output_file = output_path + "\CORP_DECEMBER2016~main9~CORP_REPORT.dbf"
SELECT 0
Use (moses_output_file) ALIAS cube_output1

**** Split the group string, only take values between months -150 and 0 ****
SELECT  2 AS t_month, padr(strextract(group,"|","|",4,1),10) AS reinsurance_book, padr(strextract(group,"|","|",5,1),10) AS Scheme, SUM(ms_fix_pay) AS mortswap_fixedleg_payment, SUM(premium_re) AS prem_reins, SUM(fixleg_res) AS quasi_fix_leg_reserve, SUM(fl_res_int) AS quasi_fix_leg_reserve_int, SUM(rfee_if) AS reinsfee_if, SUM(re_ben_res) AS reins_ben_res_if;
    FROM cube_output1;
        WHERE t_from >= -150 AND t_from <= 0;
    INTO CURSOR temp1 READWRITE;
    group by t_month, reinsurance_book, Scheme;

**** Split the group string, only take values for months 0 and 1 ****
SELECT  t_from AS t_month, padr(strextract(group,"|","|",4,1),10) AS reinsurance_book, padr(strextract(group,"|","|",5,1),10) AS Scheme, SUM(ms_fix_pay) AS mortswap_fixedleg_payment, SUM(premium_re) AS prem_reins, SUM(fixleg_res) AS quasi_fix_leg_reserve, SUM(fl_res_int) AS quasi_fix_leg_reserve_int, SUM(rfee_if) AS reinsfee_if, SUM(re_ben_res) AS reins_ben_res_if;
    FROM cube_output1;
        WHERE t_from = 0 OR t_from = 1;
    INTO CURSOR temp2 READWRITE;
    group by t_month, reinsurance_book, Scheme;

SELECT * FROM temp1;
     UNION;
SELECT * FROM temp2;
     INTO CURSOR temp3 READWRITE;
```